# Most time efficient sorting algorithm for Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Out of all the sorting algorithm like Insertion,MergeSort,QuickSort,BubbleSort and many more.Which one of these is the most time and memory efficient?

Comment: None. All of them have different timings on different sorts of input (sorted, almost sorted, sorted in reverse) and input sizes.

Comment: BogoSort it the best sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Comment: I believe this link answers your question  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/what-is-a-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-for-an-array-of-integers

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the data you are using,

however Merge sort is theoretically the quickest on average (from the selection you have given on large unordered data), however you can read [more about this here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), in the comparison section

Comment: It has to do with the randomness and sortedness of the data too.

Comment: ah yes I agree, always forget about that one!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the language affects the efficiency of sorting algorithms, apart from how well you code the algorithm you choose